# Azure Applicatoin Gateway WAF managed rule exclusion remove cli command not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

Configured Azure Application Gateway with WAF enabled,  trying to remove waf managed rule exclusion using `az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rule exclusion rule-set remove` command.  Command executed successfully.  But when try to validate managed rule not removed.

Ref: [Microsoft link - az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rule exclusion rule-set remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/waf-policy/managed-rule/exclusion/rule-set?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-application-gateway-waf-policy-managed-rule-exclusion-rule-set-remove)

Comment: Could you share the exact command that you used in your case?

Answer (score 0):

•   The command that you have used to delete the application gateway WAF managed rule exclusion set is incorrect. It should be as follows: -

```
  az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rule exclusion rule-set remove -g MyResourceGroup --policy-name MyPolicy --match-variable RequestHeaderNames --match-operator StartsWith --selector Bing --type OWASP --version 3.2 --group-name MyRuleGroup
```

Similarly, when I tried the same in my environment, I was able to delete the same successfully as shown below with the command as given above by changing the required information in it: -

[image: AGW managed ruleset exclusion]

I have already created managed ruleset exclusion as seen above in the application gateway policy. Further, I executed the command as shown below and ensured that the managed ruleset exclusion gets deleted.

[image: Powershell command for deletion]

Command executed by me: -

```
 az network application-gateway waf-policy managed-rule exclusion rule-set remove -g <resource_group_name> --policy-name AGW1Policy --match-variable RequestHeaderNames --match-operator Equals --selector https://login.microsoftonline.com --type OWASP --version 3.0
```

Output: -

[image: Azure AGW exclusion deletion]

Thus, executing the command as said above does the job for me. Accordingly, ensure to execute the Azure CLI cmdlets accordingly.

For more information regarding this, please refer to the below links accordingly: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/waf-policy/managed-rule/exclusion/rule-set?view=azure-cli-latest***

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being tracked in https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/24322
Please wait until Azure CLI 2.42.0 is released in 11/01, it should be fixed by then